# redux-forms initialization not working after upgrade to 7.x

Tags: reactjs, redux-form

I have upgraded my recct-redux application to user redux-form 7.x (latest at this time). After update, initial values aren't getting populated in the form. (It used to work with redux-forms 2.x)

Is it a bug or am i doing something silly ?

Below is my code link
https://github.com/santhoshml/Bookbild-UI/blob/master/src/components/user_profile.js

[Update] : I found the problem (but I still don't have an answer) ,

I made 3 calls to the backend server and each one returned at it own time and each kept overwriting the other. If I keep refreshing, the values keep doing disco :)

Now I have wrapped all the 3 calls in Promise.all and I can see all the fields populated, BUT when I edit and submit, onClickHandler doesn't have any updated values. 
To debug this, I printed the props in the render and it does not have the values returned from db. But surprisingly the values are populated in the textfields. This is amazingly confusing. Please help. Link below

https://github.com/santhoshml/Bookbild-UI/blob/master/src/components/user_profile.js

Thank you in advance,
Santhosh mL

Comment: Does the `initialValues` get reflected in your store and is the issue only with rendering the `initialValues` in the form `Field`s?
You can verify that easily by adding a redux-logger middleware.

Comment: I found the problem (but I still don't have an answer) , I made 3 calls to the backend server and each one returned at it own time and each kept overwriting the other. If I keep refreshing, the values keep doing disco :) Now I have wrapped all the 3 calls in Promise.all and I can see all the fields populated, BUT when I edit and submit, onClickHandler doesn't have any updated values. To debug this, I printed the props in the render and it does not have the values returned from db. But surprisingly the values are populated in the textfields. This is amazingly confusing. Please help. Link below

Comment: [link]( https://github.com/santhoshml/Bookbild-UI/blob/master/src/components/user_profile.js)

Answer (score 0):

Did you check this [documentation](http://redux-form.com/6.0.0-alpha.4/examples/initializeFromState/) out. According to that you will need to connect() to the Redux state yourself and map from the data reducer to the initialValues prop. So it should be something like this.

```
// Decorate with reduxForm(). It will read the initialValues prop provided by connect()
InitializeFromStateForm = reduxForm({
  form: 'initializeFromState'  // a unique identifier for this form
})(InitializeFromStateForm)

// You have to connect() to any reducers that you wish to connect to yourself
InitializeFromStateForm = connect(
  state => ({
    initialValues: state.account.data // pull initial values from account reducer
  }),
  { load: loadAccount }               // bind account loading action creator
)(InitializeFromStateForm)

export default InitializeFromStateForm
```

What you need to do is provide the action to load the data. Then map over the data and set it into the `initialValues` property.

Comment: I have mapDispatchToProps method, which has a load action method in it. I have mapStateToProps method, where I put the values from state into initialValues object. All of it is in the code.